# Java terminology for differentiating runtime type from compile-time type

Tags: java, types, runtime, terminology, compile-time

In Java, an `Object` can have a runtime type (which is what it was created as) and a casted type (the type you have casted it to be).

I'm wondering what are the *proper* name for these types. For instance

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

A a = new B();
```

a was created as a `B` however it was declared as an `A`. What is the proper way of referring to the type of `a` using each perspective?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's important to distinguish between the *object* (which exists at execution time, and just has its execution time type) and an *expression* (such as a variable) which has a compile-time type.

So in this case:

```
A a = new B();
```

`a` is a variable, of type `A`. Its value at execution time is a reference to an object of type `B`.

The Java language specification uses "run-time class" (e.g. for the purpose of overriding, as in [section 15.12.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.4)) for the type of an object. Elsewhere I think it just uses "type" for the type of an expression, meaning the compile-time type.

Answer (score 5):

The Java Language Specification speaks about a variable's *declared type*, the javadoc of `getClass()` about an object's *runtime class*.

Note that there is no such thing as a runtime type in Java; `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are different types, but their instances share the same runtime class.

Comment: Call getGenericType() on a Field object of type List<String> and you'll get a ParameterizedType object which refers to the List class and the String type parameter.

Comment: Yes. This reflects on the declared type of that field, and hence does not contradict my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `A` is the **reference** type while `B` is the **instance** type

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you differentiate between the type of the variable/reference and the type of the object. In the case

```
A a = new B();
```

the variable/reference would be of type `A` but the object of type `B`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the variable `a` is `A`.  There's no changing that, since it's a reference.  It happens to refer to an object of type `B`.  While you're referring to that `B` object through an `A` reference you can only treat it as though it were of type `A`.

You can later cast it to its more specific type

```
B b = (B)a;
```

and use the `B` methods on that object.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology you are looking for is the **Apparent Type** and the **Actual Type**.

```
A a = new B();
```

The **Apparent Type** is A because the compiler only knows that the object is of type A. As such at this time you cannot reference any of the B specific methods.

The **Actual Type** is B. You are allowed to cast the object (that is change its apparent type) in order to access the B specific methods.

Comment: I haven't heard of the "apparent type" terminology before. Could you tell me where you got it from? I don't think I've seen it in the JLS.

Comment: Michael J. Laszlo - Object-Oriented Programming featuring Graphical Applications in Java uses these terms to describe the difference in Types as asked in the question. The thing is, I think each author would have to make up his own terminology for something like this that is not clearly defined anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

To determine `a` is object of which class you can use:

```
/*The java.lang.Object.getClass() method returns the runtime class of an object*/   
System.out.println("a is object of: "+a.getClass());
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The op is wondering whats the terminology that can be used for  `a`.I meant to say `a` is an object of class `b`.

Answer (score 0):

[Section 15.5. Expressions and Run-Time Checks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.5) differentiates between

- the type of an expression
- the class of the referenced object

For example,

> If the **type of an expression** is a reference type, then the **class of
>   the referenced object**, or even whether the value is a reference to an
>   object rather than null, is not necessarily known at compile time.
>   There are a few places in the Java programming language where the
>   actual **class of a referenced object** affects program execution in a
>   manner that cannot be deduced from the type of the expression...
>
> [snip]
>
> An **expression whose type** is a reference type may be tested using
>   `instanceof` to find out whether the **class of the object referenced** by
>   the run-time value of the expression

Hence, applying the above language to

```
A a = new B();
```

we might say something like

> The static type of the expression `a` is `A`, despite the fact the value stored in `a` is a reference to the object of runtime class `B`.

Personally, I interpret the two concepts in the following manner (but beware I am unsure of its correctness):

- static type of the expression is purely syntactic concept existing in source code at compile time for processing by Java compiler
- runtime class of the object is actual machine construct existing in machine memory at runtime for processing by Java Virtual Machine