# Scala - Iterate a Any variable which contains List()

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
scala > 
       var a : Any = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
```

I want to iterate variable a. as it print

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Comment: The moment you have an **Any** you lose the only reason for use **Scala** which is its powerful typesystem. Why do you have an **Any** in the first place? That is a code smell that has to be solved instead of being workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections such as `List` are usually "iterated" over using `map/foreach` higher-order methods, however the reason we cannot call them directly on `a` is because compiler thinks the type of `a` is `Any` as we explicitly specified type annotation `a: Any`.

```
 var a: Any            =    List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
         |                    | 
 compile-time type          runtime class
```

`Any` does not provide `map/foreach` API so the best we can do is it to perform a runtime cast of reference `a` to class `List[_]` like so

```
if (a.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) a.asInstanceOf[List[_]].foreach(println) else ???
```

which can be equivalently sugared using pattern match

```
a match {
  case value: List[_] => value.foreach(println)
  case _ => ???
}
```

As a side-note, due to *type erasure* we can only check the "top-level"  class `List` and not, for example, `List[Int]`, hence `a.isInstanceOf[List[Int]]` is a bit misleading so I prefer expressing it `a.isInstanceOf[List[_]]`.

Comment: Top-level **class** not **type**. Pattern matching happens at runtime, where types doesn't exists.

Comment: Expanding on @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez comment see [Java terminology for differentiating runtime type from compile-time type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1514214/5205022)

Comment: Actually, I prefer this one: https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Answer (score 2):

Just use pattern matching:

```
a match {
    case l: List[Int] => l.foreach(println)
}
```

P.S.: As @IvanStanislavciuc cleverly notices, there is a warning:

> warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>   1

It's because of type erasure, but `List` needs a type parameter, so you can as well pass `Any` instead of `Int`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that match on `List[Int]` is not entirely true due to erasure of `Int`

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc good catch, I've added it in my answer, thank you!